# Mac10.13 Homebrew Installing Maven: "We (and Apple) do not provide support for this old version."

Tags: maven, homebrew

By what I get from many articles, installing maven on mac requires this command:

"brew install maven"

However, when I try this on my mac, it always ends up with the error:

"You are using macOS 10.13.
We (and Apple) do not provide support for this old version."

How can I solve this error? (I already have java installed.)

The screenshots of my terminal are attached.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PUV7C.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kHee2.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HoRrf.png)

(I have also tried manual installation with this guide: https://devwithus.com/install-maven-mac/ . But it has failed for me. Screenshots: [terminal code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/piWoO.png)
[terminal code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/601Fq.png)
[screenshot of the .bash_profile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1wdoH.png))

Comment: You don't need to use home-brew. See https://maven.apache.org

Comment: Thanks for answering. But I have also tried downloading maven manually, following this guide: https://devwithus.com/install-maven-mac/. It seems to me the manual downloading failed without a reason. I'll post the screenshot in the question.

Comment: You need the maven bin directory on your path.

Comment: Thank you so much, tgdavies. That has worked. You can't imagine how big a help your comment is for a newbie like me to learn programming!